# How to fix css3 pseudo class nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

How I can make left borders rounded? I have this code:

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.btn-group-radio input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.btn-group-radio input[type=radio]:checked + .btn {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    *background-color: #d9d9d9;
    background-color: #cccccc \9;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #d9d9d9 \9;
    background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.btn-group-radio .btn:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.btn-group-radio .btn:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-radio" role="group" id="id_offer">

            <input checked="checked" id="id_offer_0" name="offer" value="1" type="radio">
            <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default" for="id_offer_0">Offer 1</label>

            <input id="id_offer_1" name="offer" value="2" type="radio">
            <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default" for="id_offer_1">Offer 2</label>

            <input id="id_offer_2" name="offer" value="3" type="radio">
            <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default" for="id_offer_2">Offer 3</label>

        </div>
    </div>
```

For last label all works fine, for first label not working none: not as in css, not `.btn-group-radio .btn:nth-child(1)`, `.btn-g... .btn:nth-of-type(1)`, not `... label:first-child + .btn` and same.

How I understand `first-child` working, in my code, for `input` with `id="id_offer_0"`, but I don't understand why not working `nth-child` and why not working `nth-of-type`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want have left rounded corners on left button as right corners on right button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these styles:

```
#id_offer .btn:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
```

The first button is *not* the first child of its parent, but it *is* the first of its type.

You should also select based on the ID in order to overcome Bootstrap's default borders.

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.btn-group-radio input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.btn-group-radio input[type=radio]:checked + .btn {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    *background-color: #d9d9d9;
    background-color: #cccccc \9;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #d9d9d9 \9;
    background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.btn-group-radio .btn:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
#id_offer .btn:first-of-type {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-radio" role="group" id="id_offer">

            <input checked="checked" id="id_offer_0" name="offer" value="1" type="radio">
            <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default" for="id_offer_0">Offer 1</label>

            <input id="id_offer_1" name="offer" value="2" type="radio">
            <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default" for="id_offer_1">Offer 2</label>

            <input id="id_offer_2" name="offer" value="3" type="radio">
            <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default" for="id_offer_2">Offer 3</label>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works for me.
Can you describe why don't work:
`.btn-group-radio .btn:first-of-type` it goes last in div class.